# How to secure Silverlight app with Login screen/custom form

Tags: security, silverlight-4.0

I'm sure there must be a simple answer for this but I can't figure it out -

I have a Silverlight 4 OOB application that requires a login screen/security. The View shows a LoginView (Username/pw) which then passes the details to a WCF service and checks it against a database. It will return a result to the client to say if their details were valid or not. This part works fine.

Where I need some guidance is the best way of storing the fact that the user is logged on/authenticated for the current Silverlight session.

It's OOB so we can't use any web cookies/session stuff as far as I know. I assume we have to store some sort of Identity in the thread but I need some pointers please.

The other caveat is that I would like to secure all other pages to check if the user is authenticated and redirect to the login screen if not. I use the Navigation framework so I have a Frame - this may make it easier...

Any tips or pointers appreciated - I just need some ideas to get started please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the fact that the user is authenticated anywhere you like - I tend to like the Application object since it's an app-wide setting, but you can stick your "IsAuthenticaed" and/or "Roles" properties anywhere, really.

Take a look at WCF RIA Services - even if you don't want to use their solution, you can take a look at the generated authentication code it makes and see a good real-world example of how this can all work.

As for redirecting if the user is not logged in, I suggest using an `INavigationContentLoader` on your Frame, which can implement this logic in a central location.  See these two excellent posts by David Poll on the subject of INavigationContentLoader and authentication/authorization:

http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/01/01/opening-up-silverlight-4-navigation-authenticationauthorization-in-an-inavigationcontentloader/

http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/05/10/common-navigation-ui-and-authorization-driven-sitemaps/

Comment: Thanks Austin - I thought there might be a more advance way of storing the session (as opposed to a global boolean). Thanks for the links - I'll check them out! AFAIK David Poll was the actual author of the navigation framework so that would be a good place to start...

Comment: David and I worked together on the Navigation framework - he was the PM, I was the Dev.  David has LOTS of great blog posts on the topic, to boot.

Comment: Great - it doesn't come any better than that then! ;)